# Create event in iCloud calendar for different time zone

Tags: icloud, calendar, reminders, timezone

How do I create a future event in a different time zone than I'm currently on?

For example, I reside in Toronto (UTC-5) and I am going to Hong Kong (UTC+8). When I'm still in Toronto, I want to be able to create an event (in Hong Kong time) so that when I arrive in Hong Kong, the event appears correctly in the local time.

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming that you are using the website for this.  Go to iCloud, and open the Calendar app.  Click on the gear at the top-left, then click preferences.  Go to the advanced tab, and check "Enable time zone support".  Now, when you edit an event, you can select the time zone in the event information.

Answer (score 1):

Time zone support also works on the iCal app on the mac and on the iPhone.  Preferences in iCal and Settings/Mail,Contacts,Calendars on the iPhone.  These can then be synced to iCloud.

Answer (score 0):

Flexibits just released an update to their Fantastical 2 application that supports multiple timezones. Users of Microsoft Outlook will appreciate it: [New in 2.2](http://flexibits.com/fantastical/videos?pk_campaign=sparkle-2.2#whats-new-in-2.2)

Just a happy user, I don't work for the company.